# Error on Copy from OData source(MDM) to Azure blob Storage using ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory

I get the below error when trying to copy from Microsoft Dynamics Marketing OData feed to Azure Blob Storage using Azure data Factory. Can anyone guide me on resolution?

Data Type Object is not supported. Detailed Message:

> ErrorCode=DataTypeNotSupported,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Column:
>   Name,Location: Source,Format: Csv/Tsv,The data type Object
>   is not supported.,Source=,'

Answer (score 1):

That means the source data containing a column of data typed "Object" (Complex type), which is not supported in ADF.
Here's supported data type list:
Int16
Int32 
Int64
Single
Double
Decimal
Byte[]
Bool
String 
Guid
Datetime
Datetimeoffset
Timespan